# Iterate over a LinkedHashMap and Return each ‘String’ Element on a New Line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. Can anyone adice on the best way to Iterate over a LinkedHashMap and Return each ‘String’ Element on a New Line?
2. I have attempted the following getter method which does not work:

   ```
   public String returnServerStatusElementOnNewLine() {
   for(int i =0; i < BrowserFactory.serverStatusMap.size(); i++) {
       return BrowserFactory.serverStatusMap.get(i).toString();
   }
   return null;
   ```

   }
3. I need each of the listed elements within the email below to be outputted as a 'String' onto a new line: 
   [image]

Comment: You could append a newline `+ "\n"` to your return-String.

Comment: @IQV thanks for the fast response, but Eclipse makes me arracrh a return type of null, wouldnt my program just return null instead of the actual indexed String object?

Comment: The two (identical) answers should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As written, this only returns the first line.
How about this :

```
public String returnServerStatusElementOnNewLine() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i =0; i < BrowserFactory.serverStatusMap.size(); i++) {
        result.append(BrowserFactory.serverStatusMap.get(i).toString()).append("\n");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks is there a reason i get a null pointer exception if i change the method to a static method? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Change your code. Here's the modified code:

```
public String returnServerStatusElementOnNewLine() {
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   for(int i =0; i < BrowserFactory.serverStatusMap.size(); i++) {
      sb.append(BrowserFactory.serverStatusMap.get(i).toString()+"\n");
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks is there a reason i get a null pointer exception if i change the method to a static method? thanks again